# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener() not working with one item in list.

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

So I am having a problem with a spinner not firing the listener when there is only one item in the list.

Here is a break down of what i am trying to do: have a spinner with a string that displays an id/title for an object, there is a button to add items to this spinner that creates a dialog and returns and object from the dialog and updates the spinner. I currently have the spinner working to add items to the spinner after the dialog closes. the code works as intended when there are multiple items in the spinner, however if there is only one item in the spinner then no onitemselectedlistener is fired. I know this because i have debugged the code and walked over the listener, when trying to select an item when there is only one item in the list does nothing. However, if i add another item to this list i am able to select it **but only after first selecting the second or third so on  item in the list**

it is almost as if this item is if this is the item the spinner is currently selecting and therefore not generating any event for pressing it. I suppose my question would be how do i clear the spinner selection so that there is no Current selection. or would i have to do something like always have an entry in the spinner that says "Choose One" and have a check that would only do some action if the spinner's current selection wasn't equivalent to "Choose One".

my listener as it currently stands

```
  methodSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(first == false) {

                body.setText("");
                currentMethod = hold.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(methodActivity.this, "Text!" + position + ":" + currentMethod.body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// for feedback/testing purposes
                body.setEnabled(true);
                body.setText(currentMethod.body);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(methodActivity.this, "check == false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // for feedback/testing purposes
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(methodActivity.this, "onNothingSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// for feedback/testing purposes
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your condition evaluation is ambiguous. You should write something like:

if(!first){ ... }

Answer (score 3):

The Spinner will always have a selected item even if you call Spinner.setSelection( -1 ). I guess what you can do it to add a prompt
as the first option.

```
ArrayList<String> aOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
aOptions.add("Choose One");
aOptions.add("Option 1");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, aOptions);  
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank you!